# Referencing Parent Selectors: & concatenation operator fault

Tags: sass

Referencing Parent Selectors: & concatenation operator fault or I'm do something wrong.
Sass predecessor do not concatenate Class to the Element selector.

- Ubuntu 12
- ruby 1.9.3p0
- Sass 3.4.9
- Netbeans 8.2

input:

```
li{
&.current-item-menu{}
}
```

output:

```
li .current-item-menu {}
```

expect:

```
li.current-item-menu {}
```

**SCSS INPUT**

```
@mixin main-menu {
    ul {
        list-style: none;
        li{
            display: inline-block;
            float: right;
            margin: 0 59px;
            a {
                color: $second-color;
                font: 300 $big-font OpenSans;
                text-decoration: none;
                &: hover {
                    color: $active-color
                }
            }
            &.current-item-menu {
                a {
                    color: $active-color;
                    text-decoration: underline;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

nav.main-menu{
    @include main-menu;
}
```

**CSS OUTPUT**

```
nav.main-menu ul {
  list-style: none; }
  nav.main-menu ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    margin: 0 59px; }
    nav.main-menu ul li a {
      color: #274150;
      font: 300 20px OpenSans;
      text-decoration: none; }
    nav.main-menu ul li a:hover {
      color: white; }
      nav.main-menu ul li .current-item-menu a {
      color: white;
      text-decoration: underline; }
```

**I EXPECT**

```
nav.main-menu ul {
  list-style: none; }
  nav.main-menu ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    margin: 0 59px; }
    nav.main-menu ul li a {
      color: #274150;
      font: 300 20px OpenSans;
      text-decoration: none; }
    nav.main-menu ul li a:hover {
      color: white; }
      nav.main-menu ul li.current-item-menu a {
      color: white;
      text-decoration: underline; }
```

Comment: You do understand that SO is not a bug tracker for Sass, right?

Comment: Yes, I know. I'm new with sass and probably do something wrong, you know.

Comment: Norepro with Sass 3.2.12, ruby 1.9.3p484, on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Also cannot reproduce with [Sassmeister](http://sassmeister.com/).

Comment: @AntonioLazarenni ... I posted what I believe is an answer, but I am getting a ton of negative comments about trying to help you.  I will be deleting the answer.  Sorry ...

Comment: For those that forced me to delete what I posted, please tell me how to help and provide detailed code in this comment area ... in 600 characters.